# Why can't I load an image from a JSON file when I create a new window in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am writing a program in JS that receives some information from a movies API (title, description, poster image, etc) and I display a list of the latest movie releases.

In this list I want to open a new window that displays the information of a specific movie when the user clicks on the poster image.

I've already figured out how to open a new window and display most of the data I want but I am not able to display the poster.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < moviesObject.results.length; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var moviePoster = document.createElement('img');
    var divOverview = document.createElement('div');
    var divReleaseDate = document.createElement('div');

    moviePoster.setAttribute('src', 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w370_and_h556_bestv2' + moviesObject.results[i].poster_path);
    li.innerHTML = '<strong>Title: </strong>' + moviesObject.results[i].title;
    divOverview.innerHTML = '<strong>Overview: </strong>' + moviesObject.results[i].overview;
    divReleaseDate.innerHTML = '<strong>Release Date: </strong>' + moviesObject.results[i].release_date + '<br><br>';
    moviesList.appendChild(li);
    moviesList.appendChild(moviePoster);
    moviesList.appendChild(divOverview);
    moviesList.appendChild(divReleaseDate);

    moviePoster.addEventListener("click", function () {
        var newWindow = window.open();
        newWindow.document.open();
        newWindow.document.write(li.innerHTML+ "<br>");
--->    newWindow.document.write(); <-- here is where I have to display the poster
        newWindow.document.write(divOverview.innerHTML+ "<br>");
        newWindow.document.write(divReleaseDate.innerHTML+ "<br>");
        newWindow.document.close();
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you share the JSON you're using for this loop?

Comment: I can upload a picture of the part i'm using.

https://imgur.com/6kc7mnd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it because `moviePoster` doesn't have `innerHTML` set it to `outerHTML`

```
newWindow.document.write(moviePoster.outerHTML+ "<br>");
```